# How to know if the following function is returning the correct result or an error condition in `jansson`?

Tags: c, json, api

I am using the [`jansson`](https://jansson.readthedocs.org/en/2.6/index.html) JSON library for an application. I was reading the [`API`](https://jansson.readthedocs.org/en/2.6/apiref.html) and came across these functions: [`json_integer_value`](https://jansson.readthedocs.org/en/2.6/apiref.html#c.json_integer_value), [`json_real_value`](https://jansson.readthedocs.org/en/2.6/apiref.html#c.json_real_value) and [`json_number_value`](https://jansson.readthedocs.org/en/2.6/apiref.html#c.json_number_value).

The first one returns the integer value stored in a `json_t` object if it is **integer** or returns `0` on error. The other two is similar in the fact that if `json_t` is not a **number** *(integer or double)* then `0.0` is returned as the error value.

How do I know whether the returned value is an error value or actual value contained in `json_t` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `json_is_number`, `json_is_integer` and `json_is_real` macros to check the type first.